# Maintain view's flex layout with text content

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want a view to be a third of the screen (horizontally), so I create 3 of them and set `flex: 1` on each.

Now if I place a `<Text>` inside it, it will be slightly bigger than the other 2.

How do I maintain it being one third of the screen?

Here is some code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
          <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>text</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlexDirectionBasics);
```

IMAGE:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`flex:1` for each component means that it takes the whole space. Try this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 0.33, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>text</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 0.33, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
    <View style={{flex: 0.33, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
  </View>
```

Comment: That is not true, when you set `flex: 1` for each component, they distribute proportionally. try changing the `width: 50, height: 50` to `flex: 1` on the first example here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html. Have you tried your solution?

Comment: But you have nothing in your views to display so I guess flexbox expands it to the whole width.
I have not tried this on a horizontal view. It works for me on a vertical parent view. Ill check it out and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the difference while using the same code. Attached screen shot for your reference. Each block take width of 188.[image: iPhone simulator]

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, I just added a picture of what I'm seeing. I did figure out how to fix it though, adding the same width to all components (in addition to the `flex: 1`)